# Check if div is in view, if so, move to top of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a full screen swiper that when the user hits the last slide then automatically scrolls down to the content. This part does that:

```
heroSwiper.on('onReachEnd', function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".section").offset().top
      });
      heroSwiper.lockSwipes();
      heroSwiper.disableMousewheelControl();
  }, 100);

});

heroMediaSwiper.on('onReachEnd', function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".section").offset().top
      });       
      heroMediaSwiper.lockSwipes();
      heroMediaSwiper.disableMousewheelControl();
  }, 100);

});
```

If the user then scrolls back up from the content and part of the swiper is in view then I want it to scroll to the very top of the window. **So in theory, you either see a full screen swiper or the main content.**

This is supposed to get the user to the top of the window if part of the hero banner is in view:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    if ($('#hero').isOnScreen(0.3, 0.3) == true) {

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#hero").offset().top
            heroSwiper.slideTo(0);      
            heroSwiper.enableMousewheelControl();
            heroSwiper.unlockSwipes();
            heroMediaSwiper.slideTo(0);
            heroMediaSwiper.enableMousewheelControl();
            heroMediaSwiper.unlockSwipes();
        });           
    };
    }, 100);    
});
```

**At the moment it scrolls down to the main content then straight back up to the top of the page.**

This is the script to check if something is in view:

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};
```

**Or if there's a much better way to do this then please let me know!!**

Comment: I think your timeouts are clashing. Try setting timeout variable/object.  Before calling timeouts, clearTimeout the variable/object.

Comment: @Hoyen Sorry I don't quite follow, could you put it as an answer (I can accept it too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to throttle the window scroll handler calls. And you want to bypass the scroll handler altogether when your `animate` function is causing a scroll itself.

When using scroll handlers I recommend _.throttle (or debounce), which you can access if you're using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org). You can also just copy the source definition of [`_.throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-82) (along with [`_.now`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-159) which it depends on) from the [underscore annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html).

```
$(function () {
  var THROTTLE_TIME = 10; // throttle the window scroll handler
  var timer = null; // clearTimeout(timer) if you want to cancel it
  var waiting = false;

  $(window).scroll(_.throttle(function(){
    // the animation takes time, so wait for it to complete
    if(waiting) return;

    if ($('#hero').isOnScreen(0.3, 0.3) == true) {
      waiting = true; // we're going to do the animation
      // could do clearTimeout(timer) here, but waiting takes care of that
      timer = setTimeout(function(){
        var done = false;
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#hero").offset().top
          },
          function () {
            // executed twice (once for html and once for body)
            waiting = false; // animation is complete
            if(!done) {
              done = true; // only want to run this stuff once:
              heroSwiper.slideTo(0);      
              heroSwiper.enableMousewheelControl();
              heroSwiper.unlockSwipes();
              heroMediaSwiper.slideTo(0);
              heroMediaSwiper.enableMousewheelControl();
              heroMediaSwiper.unlockSwipes();
            }
          }
        );
      }, 100);
    }
  }, THROTTLE_TIME));
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to fire any of the swiper stuff so looks as though it's not getting into the function.

Comment: Have you been able to verify that with `console.log` messages or alerts?

Comment: Is there another way to do it without using underscore.js? I'm working within another developers environment and it just won't compile it! Getting _ is undefined

Comment: Sure, I'll try adding a basic throttle function now

Comment: So I added links to the underscore source which you can copy into your app and reference that way. I initially wrote a simpler custom version but I think you'd be better off using the tried and true underscore code instead...

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are triggering timeouts everytime any of those conditions are met. But you aren't cancelling any of the previous timeouts. So, all the timeouts will get triggered eventually and that is probably not what you want. Here's a snippet:

```
//Declare a timeout variable outside those functions that is visible to all of them
var myTimeout;
```

For each timeout you call do something like this:

```
clearTimeout(myTimeout);
myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    /* your code goes here */
},/* your timer goes here */);
```